# How to take the mobile field in jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I'm calling one API. They are returning response like this (jQuery ajax), for me mobile parameter I want to take how can that field name.

```
 [ {
          "user" : "xxxx@example.com",
          "mobile" : "5551212"
        } ];
```

Comment: Please try rephrasing your question, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the `mobile` field's value (945757567 in this case) via Javascript?

Comment: Would you please once check my answer HK

Answer (score 0):

Some surrounding information would really be helpful, but at first glance, it looks like you have an array of objects, that has only one object at the 0th index.

To access the "mobile" property of that object, you would use something like this:

```
*arrayName*[0]["mobile"]
```

Replace *arrayName* with the actual name of the array.

Comment: can u please make fiddle

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to make a fiddle. If you can provide some more information about what you are trying to accomplish, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it once**

```js
var data = '[ { "user" : "xxxx@example.com", "mobile" : "5551212"} ]';
    result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);     
    alert("Mobile - "+result[0].mobile);
    console.log("Mobile - "+result[0].mobile);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```